# How to access a @Named bean in PhaseListener?

Tags: jpa, jsf-2, cdi, named, phaselistener

We are using JBoss 7.1, MySQL/PostgreSQL DB, JSF 2.0 with CDI beans.

I have to implement authentification based on DB by login and password. We have a managment (administration) portal. When the client opens a restricted page without being logged in, it should redirect the request to `login.*` page if the client is not logged in.

I have tried to do that by using a `PhaseListener`.
I can Login and Logout, but when I try to open some another page I ran into a problem: 
I cannot get `@Named("user") public class UserManager` bean inside the `PhaseListener` class. I tried to get it by using `FacesContext`, & EL..., that all did not help me.

The `UserManager` validates the login and stores the logged in user as `current` property. On every request, I want to check in the `PhaseListener` if `#{user.current}` is not `null`. But I can't get the `#{user}` bean in the `PhaseListener`.

How can I get a `@Named` bean in `beforePhase()` or `afterPhase()`?

---

**Update**: here is my attempt so far:

```
private boolean loggedIn( FacesContext context ) throws IOException, ServletException
{
    LOGSTORE.debug( "loggedIn().2 " );

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getResponse();

//  ELContext elContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext();
//  UserManager userManager = (UserManager) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication()
//      .getELResolver().getValue( elContext, null, "user" );

    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession( true );
    UserManager userManager = (UserManager) session.getAttribute( "user" );

//  UserManager userManager = (UserManager) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get( "user" );

    if (!StringUtils.contains( ((HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest())
        .getRequestURL().toString(), URL_SESSION_EXPIRED ))
    {

        if (userManager == null || !userManager.isLoggedIn())
        {
            LOGSTORE.debug( " userManager is " + (userManager == null ? "" : "not ") + " null" );
            if (userManager != null)
            {
                LOGSTORE.debug( " userManager.isLoggedIn() is "
                    + (userManager.isLoggedIn() ? "TRUE" : "FALSE") );
            }
            LOGSTORE.debug( " doPhaseFilter() - START REDIRECT " );
            response.sendRedirect( request.getContextPath() + "/" + homepage + "?auth-failed" );
        }
        return false;

    } else
    {
        LOGSTORE.debug( "loggedIn().3 it is " + homepage );
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code which you tried when you said *"i tried to get it by using FacesContext, & EL..., that all did not help me"*

Comment: I have added snippet above - in which i try to get bean in SessionPhaseListener

Answer (score 7):

A session scoped CDI managed bean is not stored in the HTTP session the same way as a normal session scoped JSF managed bean. A session scoped JSF managed is indeed stored in the session by the bean name as key. A session scoped CDI managed bean is however abstracted further away through another map in the session scope.

You need to get it by evaluating EL programmatically instead of grabbing it from the session map. Your EL resolver attempt has one mistake, the value does not contain any `#{}` expression.

```
ELContext elContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext();
UserManager userManager = (UserManager) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication()
    .getELResolver().getValue(elContext, null, "user");
```

Fix it accordingly:

```
ELContext elContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext();
UserManager userManager = (UserManager) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication()
    .getELResolver().getValue(elContext, null, "#{user}");
```

By the way, a shorthand for the above is the `Application#evaluateExpressionGet()`:

```
UserManager userManager = context.getApplication()
    .evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{user}", UserManager.class);
```

Note that you've the `FacesContext context` also already there as method argument.

Comment: Wonderful! I was trying all kinds of stuff in vain with only this example [link](http://anonsvn.icesoft.org/repo/icefaces/trunk/icefaces/samples/address-demo/src/com/icesoft/applications/faces/address/PhaseSync.java). Now I can go to sleep! Thanks again BalusC.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following code to get a reference to the CDI beans from inside the `PhaseListener`.

```
public BeanManager getBeanManager() {
    BeanManager beanManager = null;
    try {
        InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
        beanManager = (BeanManager) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Couldn't get BeanManager through JNDI", e);
    }
    return beanManager;
}

public <T> T getBean(final Class<T> clazz) {
    BeanManager bm = getBeanManager();
    Bean<T> bean = (Bean<T>) bm.getBeans(clazz).iterator().next();
    CreationalContext<T> ctx = bm.createCreationalContext(bean);
    return (T) bm.getReference(bean, clazz, ctx);
}
```

So to get the bean you would call it like the following.

```
DataManager dataManager = getBean(DataManager.class);
```

The bean in this case is a `@Dependent` bean which is being used in the `PhaseListener`.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is fixed in the next version of JSF which has real CDI integration for this stuff. What you will need to do (and maintain portability) is to lookup the BeanManager via JNDI, then get the named bean from the BeanManager.

Answer (score 0):

Another posibility would be to use [Seam Faces](http://seamframework.org/Seam3/FacesModule). It is a portable CDI extension and allows you to observe [faces events](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/faces/latest/reference/en-US/html/events.html).